# Windows 7 Backup and Restore from External HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, system-restore

I have a Dell Optiplex 760 with 160Gb HDD. It runs Windows 7, 32-bit on 50Gb primary partition of the HDD and the rest 100 Gb is used as an extended partition. I want to make a backup of Windows (system image) including all the library data of the primary partition onto an external HDD and then restore it to the same internal HDD formatted with different HDD partitions, i.e., 100Gb for Windows (Primary), and rest 50Gb for Backup(Extended). Is that possible? Does the created Windows system image contain HDD partition information also?

How do I create a Recovery Drive (like in HP and Compaq Desktop PC's) for System Recovery?

Comment: Bad idea, what if the hard drive fails"? Best to make an image of the hard drive system partions and store it on a usb hard drive. Plenty of free software that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore to a HDD with different partition, but the partition size of the new drive at least the same as the old drive's partition. So based on your description, it may work.
It will contain the partition information about system partition related.
How to create a recovery drive:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026852/windows-create-a-recovery-drive